# Change Group Names Based on Parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a dynamic report that has the ability to change the group names at the start of the report.

Here's my scenario:

We have charts which show sales activity for all of our sales staff. At the bottom of the graph is the names of all sales staff. What I'm trying to do is anonymize the namea to show how the staff stack up against each other.

I'm currently doing this through a formula in the group name that replaces all but one name with a space. I'd like to do this using one report instead of creating 25 seperate reports using different code for each user.

My current formula looks like this:

```
IF {Database.DataField} = "BILL" THEN TOTEXT("BILL")
ELSE IF {Database.DataField} = "CORY" THEN TOTEXT("")
ELSE {Database.DataField}
```

My report data looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWwae.png

My graph looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wge0f.png

Any way to make this dynamic to one report?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple cypher like [ROT-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) would be appropriate.

Create a custom function that performs the substitution, then call it from your formula field:

```
//{@salesperson}
//encode the salesperson's name
Rot13({Database.DataField})
```

A more-sophisticated option would be to pass the text through a [hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) but this would probably require you to use a [user-function library (UFL)](http://www.slxdeveloper.com/page.aspx?action=viewarticle&articleid=103).

Comment: That looks like a good idea, but I'm not seeing this function in Crystal Reports 2011. This is the actual reporting software, BTW.